# How to query another microservice in saga pattern

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, saga

I am developing a spring boot microservice application adopting the Saga Orchestration pattern and Database-per-service design. I understand that the pattern should be async. However, I have a use case where I have a microservice that need to query for data from another service.

Below is the context:

I have 2 services, `Order` and `Customer`. `Order` has a `customerId` field. When the client (via HTTP) requests for all orders, `Order` will need to query `Customer` for the `customerName` with that particular `customerId`. This will return all orders along side customer name, instead of customer id, for that order.

Solution considered:

1. Using synchronous communication, either REST or gRPC for that query from `Order` to `Customer`. Easy to maintain but risk of data loss.
2. A duplicated `Customer` table in `Order`. This eliminates the need for communication outside of `Order`, but need to maintain the data sync.

Answer (score 2):

A good pattern to address this is event sourcing.  The Customer service sends an event/message when it does data operations (customerId and customerName events for example) and the Order service listens for these events. The Order service may also request replays of events/messages if necessary. This decouples the services, prevents static interdependencies, etc.  Hope this helps. I can elaborate if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes I have researched on it and seems like it is a good pattern. However, implementing it is a different story. Does you have any advice on the implementation?

Comment: The use case requirements and products used definitely have a bearing.For example, if you are using a database with change data capture capability you can subscribe to notifications of specific data changes using that. Similarly, you can use the outbox pattern where the data/tx logs of a database are tailed/streamed as events (eg with kafka).These will require you to have MSes that are idempotent to handle dupe msgs and/or message loss, replay, etc. Oracle db has a nice solution as it has the AQ msging engine built in such that the data+event ops are atomic, guaranteed exact once delivery,etc.